How to see the vector field $[X,Y]$ as map $M\to TM$?
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X:M\to TM$ a vector field which sends $p$ to a linear map $X_p :C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $X_p (f)=\frac{d(f\circ c)(t)}{dt}|_{t=0}$ where $c$ is a curve such that $c(0)=p$. We can see $X$ as a derivation $X:C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ defined by $f\mapsto X(f)$ in which $X(f):M\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $X(f)(p)=X_p (f)$. In this way we can define a Lie bracket $[\cdot ,\cdot ]:\chi (M)\times \chi (M)\to \chi (M)$ by $(X,Y)\mapsto [X,Y]$ where $[X,Y]:C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ defined by $[X,Y]=X\circ Y-Y\circ X$.
My question is that how can I see derivation $[X,Y]$ as a vector field $M\to TM$? In general, how can we construct a vector field from a derivation $D:C^{\infty}(M)\to C^{\infty}(M)$ ?

Sections $M\to TM$ should be the same thing as derivations on $C^\infty(M)$ but seeing this may depend on how you've defined $TM$

@FShrike By $TM$ I mean $\bigcup_{p\in M}T_pM=\bigcup_{p}{ p}\times T_p M$. Could you please explain it a little bit more?

Aha but how have you defined $T_pM$? With derivations or with tangent vectors?

@FShrike with derivations. $X_p \in T_p M$ is defined as $X_p :C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ by $X_p (f)=d(f\circ \gamma)/dt|_{t=0}$ where $\gamma :\mathbb{R}\to M$ with $\gamma (0)=p$.

Hang on, that's both! You're mixing the tangent curve derivative and the derivation definitions. Here, $\gamma$ would need to relate to $X$ and visa versa. Certainly each $\gamma$ determines an $X$ and less obviously each $X$ should determine a $\gamma$

But anyway. If $D:C^\infty\to C^\infty$ is a derivation, each $p\in M$ gives you a new derivation $C^\infty\to M$ given by $f\mapsto D(f)(m)$. This should be the assignment $M\to TM$

@FShrike You are right. I got it. Thank you very much.
